# TFL JSON data parsing

Tags: java, android, json

Can anyone help me to parse this JSON data that returns from TFL london.

```
 [4,"1.0",1349088458923]
 [1,"Woolwich Ferry","161",1349088648000]
 [1,"Woolwich Ferry","177",1349088912000]
 [1,"Woolwich Ferry","161",1349089159000]
 [1,"Woolwich Ferry","180",1349089207000]
 [1,"Woolwich Ferry","177",1349089408000]
 [1,"Woolwich Ferry","472",1349089175000]
 [1,"Woolwich Ferry","161",1349089771000]
 [1,"Woolwich Ferry","472",1349089594000]
 [1,"Woolwich Ferry","180",1349089860000]
 [1,"Woolwich Ferry","472",1349088522000]
 [1,"Woolwich Ferry","177",1349090001000]
 [1,"Woolwich Ferry","472",1349088841000]
 [1,"Woolwich Ferry","472",1349089942000]
```

Comment: paste your response on **jsonlint.com** and click on validate button

Comment: It is not json response.If you have posted half of your response then you can update your post by posting full response of your json output.

Comment: anyone who doubt with this output can check this url :http://countdown.api.tfl.gov.uk/interfaces/ura/instant_V1?StopCode1=50775

Comment: There are hundreds of posts about parsing JSON data in Android, please check the related posts, passing a valid json response to `JSONObject`

Comment: I know how to parse valid json response. I have already worked on various android apps that worked on json responses. but only this one is wierd.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't mean to insult your experience, it wasn't obvious from your question. That API is not producing valid JSON so it wont parse, to be valid it would need to be this: http://gist.github.com/3810999 - do you have a link to the api documentation, I'll take a look

Comment: Yeah sure, you can have look on this document.

Comment: http://www.tfl.gov.uk/assets/downloads/businessandpartners/tfl-live-bus-arrivals-api-documentation.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is a list of JSON arrays, one per line. For each line, parse it using the JSON parser, and then process it as required by your application.

Answer (score -1):

It does not look like a valid json response. It is CSV format response.

EDIT: As suggested by Shaun in the comments, if it is JsonArray, use jsonparsers.

Comment: it should be comment.pls dont post comments as answers

Comment: I thought about that once but didn't try. I'll try it to convert it to csv and then valid json. thanks.

Comment: Thank again. I solved the problem with converting into csv and got the desire output.

Comment: It is not a CSV format. It is a list of JSON arrays, one per line.

Answer (score -1):

I think this your showned output is in csv format so you need to convert it to json . So for that you can refer the following [example](https://github.com/darwin/csv2json)

Comment: String csv = "lastName,dob,age,hobby,firstName\n" + 
          "Kasireddi,Thu May 06 00:00:00 IST 2010,2,Singing,Sriram\n" + 
          "Kasireddi,Mon Sep 06 00:00:00 IST 1982,29,Painting,Sudhakar";
    
    JSONArray array = CDL.toJSONArray(csv);
    System.out.println(array.toString(2));

Comment: This is also way to convert csv to json.

Comment: This is not a CSV response.